# Where can I find a high quality real globe of a decent size without axis?

Tags: cartography, 3d, globe

I'm trying to find a physical [globe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globe) of a high map quality that *doesn't have any axis or bearings* as the axis mounted on standard desk globes completely obscures the arctic regions.

High-quality map globes [seem to be available](http://www.maps.com/map.aspx?cid=7,66&pid=17216) but repeated searches failed me to find a globe model of a decent size (say 12'' and up) with an Atlas quality map and *without* axis, so that one can view the earth from any angle and the arctic regions are fully mapped and easily visible. Do you know whether/where such a product exists?

---

Edit: Magnetic globes won't do, as they are too small and [the one example from an answer](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=toys-and-games&field-keywords=Magnetic%20Floating%20Globe&x=0&y=0) also obscures the polar regions through its magnets.

What I'd really like is a complete sphere without any knobs or visible seams (I don't mind seams if they are well covered) that can be placed in a holder. Inflatable globes seem quite OK, but their map-quality is very low as far as I could find.

Hmmm ... it seems these would go in the right direction (as far as I can trust the images): http://www.worldglobeu.com/movaglobes -- but they only go up to 8,5'' the maps look so-so and they are insanely expensive for the size and map-quality they offer.

[This one](http://www.worldglobeu.com/product/ES-30BGFS) seems to get the axis/seam thing halfway right, but the mapwork is more artistic that accurate: [image: Blue Green Earthsphere].

(Note that if that globe offered an [Atlas quality map](http://www.timesatlas.com/TimesAtlasRange/Pages/AtlasDetail.aspx?IDNumber=63021) it's price tag *might* even be acceptable at 30''.)

Comment: Xmas edition? ;] http://bsc-geography.blogspot.com/2011/12/tis-season.html

Answer (score 2):

[Joe Roubal](http://roubalmapping.com/) makes beautiful globes that have been on my wishlist for some time. Standard size range is 18" - 30", using your data if desired (I suggest the high quality and free [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/)). He also sells kits through http://www.realworldglobes.com/ if you'd like to build your own. All the website examples use the stands, and thus obscure something, but I'm sure he'd be happy to make one that sits on a donut cushion instead.

[image: 18" sat map glob on post stand]

Comment: These look great. Now I need to convince my wife to spend a fortune on a globe ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Did you ask Chaplin?

[image]

Comment: +1 for humor? ;-) ... I *actually* watched the scene on YouTube to see what they used in the film, but it is an inflatable one and I doubt the map is of good quality. :-P

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a german company that seems to make nice ones too: http://www.columbus-verlag.de/index/Handfertigung.html

[Kaschierung http://www.columbus-verlag.de/index/Handfertigung_files/kaschieren_01.jpg](http://www.columbus-verlag.de/index/Handfertigung_files/kaschieren_01.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

So you need a floating (Magnetic) Globe?

http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dtoys-and-games&field-keywords=Magnetic+Floating+Globe&x=0&y=0

[image]

Max size is 8" (203mm)

Can be quite heavy if larger.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't that globe have huge magnets on the top and bottom, obscuring the polar regions?

Comment: It's an example - there are others available - but I wouldn't say the cartography is the best - there will need to be compromise.

Comment: Fair enough. Most of the floating globes in the amazon link seem to be novelty globes and not so sharp on the cartography side. Still, it gives an idea of what to look for.

Comment: If there is unlimited budget the high quality (even very small globes) Globes can run into the many $$$$.

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for. See my edit.

Comment: @Mapperz - When searching, I had the feeling the small&&expensive globes were most often expensive because they used an expansive material, not so much for the mapwork.

Answer (score 1):

[Bellerby & Co.](http://www.bellerbyandco.com/index.php/globes/the-desk-globes/the-standard.html) makes really nice desktop models, decently sized at 23cm.

[image]

And the price is nice too :-) A mere 1k pounds.