# Creating map gores in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, globe

Does anyone have clear instructions on creating [gores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gore_(segment)) for a globe in ArcGIS?

I have tried to work with these:

http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=1725

But have become lost. I have been using this world border shapefile:

http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php

Can anyone give some clear advice on how to create a set of globe gores in ArcGIS?

Comment: Related for open source: [Discontinuous or Interrupted map projections?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1775/discontinuous-or-interrupted-map-projections)

Comment: You might find this previous question useful: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53578/does-anyone-know-the-proj4-coordinte-reference-system-command-line-for-rectangul

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being an online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.